# How to update any text filed when the user is select an option from a dropdown-menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a [UI](http://jsfiddle.net/c00p933w/show/) like this image below :

[image]

My main goal is to **update** the text filed when the user is select an option from a dropdown menu.

---

Variables

```
var section_num = $('#as-section-num');
var problem_set = $('#as-problem-set');
var start_time = $('#as-start-time');
var student_am = $('#as-student-am');
var due_time = $('#as-due-time');
var submit = $('#as-submit');
var avg_score = $('#as-avgscore');

var danger= $('#pc-danger');
var danger_list = $('#pc-danger-list');
var warning= $('#pc-warning');
var warning_list = $('#pc-warning-list');
var success= $('#pc-success');
var success_list = $('#pc-success-list');
```

Object

```
var A =  {

      "section_num":"2.2",
      "problem_set":"Same",
      "start_time":"7/20/2015 10:00 am",
      "student_am":"9",
      "due_time":"7/20/2015 11:00 am",
      "submit":"9",
      "avg_score":"90",
      "danger":"5",
      "danger_list":"5,10,15,19,23",
      "warning":"8",
      "warning_list":"3,7,11,13,14,16,21,22",
      "success":"12",
      "success_list":"1,2,4,6,8,9,12,17,18,20,24,25",

    };
```

On click - I want to set the value to those fields from my object `A`. I couldn't get it to set.

```
$('#group-a').click(function () {

      section_num.innerHTML  = A.section_num;
      problem_set.innerHTML  = A.problem_set;
      start_time.innerHTML   = A.start_time;
      student_am.innerHTML   = A.student_am;
      due_time.innerHTML     = A.due_time;
      submit.innerHTML       = A.submit;
      avg_score.innerHTML    = A.avgscore;
      danger.innerHTML       = A.danger;
      danger_list.innerHTML  = A.danger_list;
      warning.innerHTML      = A.warning;
      warning_list.innerHTML = A.warning_list;
      success.innerHTML      = A.success;
      success_list.innerHTML = A.success_list;

    });
```

---

## Result

I couldn't get any text to set.
I got 0 error on my console.

I hope someone can shed the light on this.

Here is what I have now on [my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c00p933w/)

Comment: I believe the on `Click` on an `id` will work too. I'm not too worried about that. I'm very curious why my `innerHTML` doesn't work. Surprisingly, I've tried `.text()` also. Same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `html` instead of `innerHTML`:

```
$('#group-a').click(function () {
    section_num.html(A.section_num);
    problem_set.html(A.problem_set);
    start_time.html(A.start_time);
    student_am.html(A.student_am);
    due_time.html(A.due_time);
    submit.html(A.submit);
    avg_score.html(A.avgscore);
    danger.html(A.danger);
    danger_list.html(A.danger_list);
    warning.html(A.warning);
    warning_list.html(A.warning_list);
    success.html(A.success);
    success_list.html(A.success_list);
});



$('#group-b').click(function () {
    section_num.html(B.section_num);
    problem_set.html(B.problem_set);
    start_time.html(B.start_time);
    student_am.html(B.student_am);
    due_time.html(B.due_time);
    submit.html(B.submit);
    avg_score.html(B.avgscore);
    danger.html(B.danger);
    danger_list.html(B.danger_list);
    warning.html(B.warning);
    warning_list.html(B.warning_list);
    success.html(B.success);
    success_list.html(B.success_list);

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/c00p933w/1/

> Set the HTML contents of each element in the set of matched elements.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/html

Comment: It works. Thank-you @Tushar. Is what I have now is the proper way of doing it ? If not, do you have any last advise for me ?

Comment: @开发人员 Yes, this is the proper way to do it. Since you are setting some text inside an element.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `innerHtml` by `html`.

For example, instead of:

```
section_num.innerHTML = A.section_num;
```

try:

```
section_num.html(A.section_num);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use code bellow

```
var section_num = $('#as-section-num');
    var problem_set = $('#as-problem-set');
    var start_time = $('#as-start-time');
    var student_am = $('#as-student-am');
    var due_time = $('#as-due-time');
    var submit = $('#as-submit');
    var avg_score = $('#as-avgscore');

    var danger= $('#pc-danger');
    var danger_list = $('#pc-danger-list');
    var warning= $('#pc-warning');
    var warning_list = $('#pc-warning-list');
    var success= $('#pc-success');
    var success_list = $('#pc-success-list');

    var A =  {
      "section_num":"2.2",
      "problem_set":"Same",
      "start_time":"7/20/2015 10:00 am",
      "student_am":"9",
      "due_time":"7/20/2015 11:00 am",
      "submit":"9",
      "avg_score":"90",
      "danger":"5",
      "danger_list":"5,10,15,19,23",
      "warning":"8",
      "warning_list":"3,7,11,13,14,16,21,22",
      "success":"12",
      "success_list":"1,2,4,6,8,9,12,17,18,20,24,25",
    };

    var B =  {
      "section_num":"2.3",
      "problem_set":"Not the same",
      "start_time":"6/19/2015 1:00 pm",
      "student_am":"9",
      "due_time":"6/19/2015 2:00 pm",
      "submit":"7",
      "avg_score":"100",
      "danger":"10",
      "danger_list":"11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20",
      "warning":"10",
      "warning_list":"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10",
      "success":"5",
      "success_list":"21,21,23,24,25",
    };

$('.wrapper-dropdown-1 .group').click(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if(id == 'group-a'){
      section_num.html(A.section_num);
      problem_set.html(A.problem_set);
      start_time.html(A.start_time);
      student_am.html(A.student_am);
      due_time.html(A.due_time);
      submit.html(A.submit);
      avg_score.html(A.avgscore);
      danger.html(A.danger);
      danger_list.html(A.danger_list);
      warning.html(A.warning);
      warning_list.html(A.warning_list);
      success.html(A.success);
      success_list.html(A.success_list);
    }
    else if(id == 'group-b'){
      section_num.html(B.section_num);
      problem_set.html(B.problem_set);
      start_time.html(B.start_time);
      student_am.html(B.student_am);
      due_time.html(B.due_time);
      submit.html(B.submit);
      avg_score.html(B.avgscore);
      danger.html( B.danger);
      danger_list.html(B.danger_list);
      warning.html(B.warning);
      warning_list.html(B.warning_list);
      success.html( B.success);
      success_list.html(B.success_list);    
    }
 });
```